# Vue-draggable limit list to 1 element

Tags: vue.js, jquery-ui-draggable, sortablejs, vuedraggable

Here I am trying to implement cloning an element from rankings list and put it in either of the two lists (list1 & list2). Everything seems to be working, I am able to drag and put but it looks like binding does not work as the two lists are not affected, because the watchers do not run when I drag an element to a list. Also, the clone function does not print the message to the console. I was using [this example](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/custom-clone.vue) as a reference.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <draggable
          @change="handleChange"
          :list="list1"
          :group="{ name: 'fighter', pull: false, put: true }"
        ></draggable>
      </div>
      <div>
        <draggable 
          @change="handleChange"
          :list="list2" 
          :group="{ name: 'fighter', pull: false, put: true }
        ></draggable>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <div v-for="wc in rankings" :key="wc.wclass">
        <Card>
          <draggable :clone="clone" 
                     :group="{ name: 'fighter', pull: 'clone', put: false }"
          >
            <div class="cell" v-for="(fighter, idx) in wc.fighters" :key="fighter[0]">
                <div class="ranking">
                  {{ idx + 1 }}
                </div>
                <div class="name">
                  {{ fighter[0] }}
                </div>
            </div>
          </draggable>
        </Card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
import draggable from "vuedraggable";

export default {
  components: {
    draggable
  },
  data() {
    return {
      rankings: [],
      list1: [],
      list2: []
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getRankingLabel(label) {
      if (!label || label == "NR") return 0;
      if (label.split(" ").indexOf("increased") !== -1) return 1;
      if (label.split(" ").indexOf("decreased") !== -1) return -1;
    },
    clone({ id }) {
      console.log("cloning");
      return {
        id: id + "-clone",
        name: id
      };
    },
    handleChange(event) {
      console.log(event);
    }
  },
  watch: { 
    // here I am keeping the length of both lists at 1  
    list1: function(val) {
      console.log(val); // nothing prints, as the watcher does not run
      if (val.length > 1) {
        this.fighter_one.pop();
      }
    },
    list2: function(val) {
      console.log(val); // nothing prints, as the watcher does not run
      if (val.length > 1) {
        this.fighter_two.pop();
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:3000")
      .then(res => {
        this.rankings = res.data;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing the [`@change`](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/blob/master/example/components/custom-clone.vue#L10) handler for both of your `draggable` lists.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda I've tried adding the change handler, it didn't console log anything as well

Comment: Can you update your code to include the change handler? The watch functions will only run if you update `this.list1` or `this.list2` which it doesn't look like you are doing anywhere

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda added the 'handleChange' method. For some reason I thought that  :list="list1" takes care of updating the list, but that's one way binding, so it doesn't update the list. Do you have any suggestions on how to add v-model to the binding? Also, the clone function should be executing right? But it doesn't print anything to the console.

Comment: The draggbale component under the card does not have any list props or v-model binding. This can not work.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted in the comments, your problem is likely related the `<draggable>` tag not containing either a `:list` prop or `v-model`.

With that said, you can limit the size of a list to 1 by calling the `splice(1)` method on the list in the `@change` event.

```
<draggable :list="list1" group="fighter" @change="list1.splice(1)">
              {{ list1.length }}
</draggable>
```